# Determine if bootstrap column content is on left or right side (For Jquery sortable)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created a page where users are supposed to fill out different information where there are tags to show the user where to fill in. 
The content can either be taking full with (col-12) or right/left side (col-6) and if the content is taking up half of the page, I want to be able to move the tag (blue circle) to the same side as to where the content is. The user will be able to move the content to left/right side using Jquery UI sortable.

See picture below:
[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="blockContent">
      <span class="grip-bar block-handle ui-sortable-handle"></span>
      <div class="block">
        <i class="icon icon-tag-warning hand left-info"></i>        
        <p>Field with tag to fill in:
          <input class="width-full width-dynamic input-line l-input-icon">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="blockContent">
      <span class="grip-bar block-handle ui-sortable-handle"></span>
      <div class="block">
        <i class="icon icon-tag-warning hand left-info"></i> 
        <p class="bold">Some text</p>       
        <p>Fill in this field:
          <input class="width-full width-dynamic input-line l-input-icon">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any hints or tips how to be able to determine side of the content to set the tag on the correct side? Either with CSS or Jquery?

**EDIT:**

The user can generate their own col-6 or col-12 so it's not possible to add a class like "left" or "right" for the column which the content/block could use (As far as I'm aware).

Comment: Your question is a little confusing to me. Maybe you are looking for offset? eg `.col-md-offset-2`?

Comment: I don't think it's offset I'm after, I'm only using col-6, and need to know if the column is on the right or left side. As the user might move the content within col-6 from left to right or the other way around, the circle/tag should move to the "right" side of the paper when the user moves the content.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. What you could do is create an event for when the user drags the columns, to run your own function, and attach a class or attribute to the columns so you know which is which. I am not very familiar with jquery UI, but I am sure there is likely a `$(#ele).on('drag')` or something similar.

Comment: I was just going to edit my question with information that it I can't attach e.g "left" or "right" to the class as the user can generate col-6 and col-12 to add new content below. Any other possible solutions? Else I will have to rethink my code as that is the best solution so far to try something like you said

Comment: I mean, it wouldn't have to be a class, you could throw any attribute on there, assuming that there is some information that comes through the event argument from the "on drag", you could just throw any old attribute on the element so you know which is which. If you could provide me a fiddle with some javascript, I could help more.

Comment: Here is an example!
https://jsfiddle.net/kytenz/t5fpn10s/

Comment: sorry about that, I ended up out of town over the whole weekend. Sounds like you got it figured out though!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the help from Truextacy for pointing me in the right direction.

When generating the HTML code, I added a class to to each column that would be named tag-left or tag-right and then the blocks on sortable would check the new column's tag side and set the CSS accordingly.